# Multiple JSON Bokeh Plots in Django Template -- Possible?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, bokeh

I feel that I'm almost there on this one, but on the other hand I might be going about this completely wrong.  I am trying to generate **several** JSON items to load as bokeh plots in my Django template.  I'm getting really hung up on the warning that says Bokeh isn't defined in my script that embeds it, despite having the stylesheets and scripts and jQuery scripts that seem necessary.  It continually says "Bokeh is not defined" and advises me to define it or to add it as a global variable.

Is this way the wrong way?

Should I be using a Bokeh server?

```
<script>
...
Bokeh.embed.embed_item(json_dict.year);   #ERROR IS HERE, DOESN'T RECOGNIZE BOKEH
...
</script>
```

Essentially, my question is: what is the best way to embed **multiple** bokeh plots into a django template?  Is it even advisable?

Please forgive my confusion, I've been staring at documentation for far too long.

Comment: note that I have loaded CDN.render() as a resource in my template

Comment: Have you actually looked at what is showing up in the rendered template? It should be script tags similar to the ones described here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components What about the network pane in your browser debugger? Does it show any attempts to load BokehJS at all? If so, does it show errors?

Comment: @bigreddot I am getting:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined
    at Object.n.embed_item (bokeh-1.3.4.min.js:31)
    at graphs:167"

Comment: The JSON items are being logged successfully per console.log(), they just aren't being recognized?

Comment: Okay, so it looks like my major problem is passing a list/dictionary of the json objects to the template.  It can't seem to parse them.  Should I encode them as JSON when I pass them?  And by that, I don't mean the graph items (those are already in json).

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, I have the list working, but the dictionary is telling me there's an "unexpected number" and won't move forward from there.

Comment: At long last, it was 100% how I was loading my variables.  It works!  Thanks for the prompt to get me thinking.  I've been referencing your bokeh posts for like a week now!

Comment: Glad it's working, if you want to self-answer with details I'm happy to upvote.